# Django request.REQUEST is truncating data

Tags: python, ajax, django, request, django-views

So I have this form (some elements removed for clarity)

```
<form id="{{ section }}-submission-form{{ cell_id }}">

    <input type=hidden name="section" value="{{ section }}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="school" id="{{ section }}-submit-school{{ cell_id }}" />


    {% if section == "posts" %}
        <input type=hidden name="url" />
        <textarea class="{{ section }}txtinput{{ cell_id }}" name="text-submission"
                  default="{% if is_advice %}What's your question?{% else %}What's on your mind?{% endif %}"
                  id="{{ section }}-suggestion-box{{ cell_id }}"
                  style="margin: 0 0 .5em 0;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 14px; width: 410px;"
                  rows='8'></textarea>
        <br />
    {% endif %}
    {% if section == "photos" %}
        <span style='line-height: 40px;'>
        <label class="photouploadlabel">URL</label><input type="text" name="image-url" style="width: 335px" /><br>
        <label class="photouploadlabel">File</label><input type="file" name="image-file" style="width: 335px"/><br>
        <label class="photouploadlabel">Caption</label><input type="text" id="image-caption{{ cell_id }}"
                                                              name="image-caption" style="width: 335px" default="optional"/>
        </span>
    {% endif %}


    <div id="{{ section }}-bottomdiv{{ cell_id }}" style="height: 45px; margin-top: .5em; width: 413px;">
        <div style="height: 45px">
        <label id="{{ section }}-tagsbutton{{ cell_id }}"
               style="margin-right: .5em; cursor: pointer; vertical-align: bottom; float:left; line-height: 1.8em;">Tags</label>

        <input id="{{ section }}-tagsinput{{ cell_id }}" type="text" name="tags-list" style="position: relative"/>
                    <button id="send-{{ section }}-suggestion{{ cell_id }}" disabled="disabled"
                style="float:right; position: relative; bottom: 7px; right: -4px;">Post</button>
        </div>
```

The tags-list input is turned into an autocomplete and users select tags, which are then added to a global js variable "selected tags". When the user presses "Post", I have this code:

```
           alert(selectedtags);
       $("#"+section+"-submission-form"+cellid).ajaxSubmit({
           url: '/save-suggestion/',
           type: 'post',
           data: {'tags': selectedtags },
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function(response){
               clear_text(section, cellid);
               location.reload();
           },
```

Here's the weird bit: whichever section I'm in, the alert works. However, if I print request.REQUEST on the server side, if the section is photos I get

```
{u'image-url': u'http://i.imgur.com/vUxla.jpg', u'tags-list': u'', u'tags': u'wtf,crazy,pics', u'section': u'photos', u'school': u'1997', u'anonymity-level': u'schoolandmajor', u'image-file': u'', u'image-caption': u''}
```

i.e. what I want. But if the section is posts, I get

```
{u'text-submission': u'wtf', u'school': u'1997', u'tags-list': u'', u'url': u'', u'section': u'posts', u'tags[]': u'crazy', u'anonymity-level': u'schoolandmajor'}
```

So not only is it renamed to tags[] (which I've seen before and am not too concerned about, but...), it also truncates my tag list to just the last entry.

Does anyone have any idea what I could be doing wrong?

EDIT: upon further inspection, this is something that using request.REQUEST is doing, as opposed to request.POST.

So, still, what is going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`request.REQUEST` is a `MergedDict` which contains a `QueryDict` for POST and one for GET. When iterating the MergedDict, you will get single values for each key, which is what the `__str__` method does for that class. You can get around this by using `QueryDict.getlist` like so:

```
print request.REQUEST.getlist('tags[]')
```

Which in my test, yields:

```
[u'asd', u'123']
```

If I just `print request.REQUEST['tags[]']`, I get just *123*.

Comment: +1 for actually showing the issue in the django code (that is not even shown)

Comment: hm... I thought I had tried that exact code snippet... perhaps not. I'll try again. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I'm using that exact code snippet and sometimes it's not working... showing up as tags instead of tags[]....

Comment: Set the following
`jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;` per http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-post-1-4-1-is-appending-to-vars-when-posting-from-array-within-array and always use *tags* (no brackets)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue appears to be in your JavaScript. The data you receive on both requests appear to be different. In the first request `tags` is the following string:

```
u'tags': u'wtf,crazy,pics'
```

In the latter, though, tags is set as the following:

```
u'tags[]': u'crazy'
```

As you very well mentioned, the name is changed and only the last item is kept. This difference appears to be stemming from the fact that on the first request `tags` is not a list but a single string of comma-separated strings.

I think that you will solve your issue by changing your code to make the handling of that variable consistent it. Based on the fact that sending out a list is causing issues to you may suggest that the way to go is the comma-separated string of your first request.

The fact that you are not getting the right data when using a list is probably due to the parser on the receiving side of the JSON data as it is technically an object and an object can not have two members with the same name (and your code is probably sending them all as `tags[]`).

Comment: these are not different requests... they're different ways django is handling the same request.